# How to fix java.io.InvalidClassException: org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have recently upgraded the Spring of my spring boot application, as a result, the underlying Spring Security Core upgraded to 5.4.5.

Now while launching the Spring Boot application, I am seeing following issue:

```
org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel - handleException / java.io.InvalidClassException: 
org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl; local class incompatible: 
stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 530, local class serialVersionUID = 540
```

In this context, I found this post on GitHub: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/9204 and https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/3736.

But I could not figure out how to solve this issue. Could anyone please help here? Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you are messing with versions yourself instead of using the proper starters.

Comment: @M.Deinum Could you please give some pointers regarding how to fix this?

Comment: Don't mess with versions yourself (unless you knwo what you are doing) and use the starters to include dependencies (and not individual dependencies). It feels like the latter is what you are doing, now upgrading Spring Boot breaks things because and old dependency is being used.

Comment: Post your pom.xml

Answer (score 4):

In https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/9204 you can find:
"Spring Security is not intended to be serialized between versions"

This is mind blowing. So all users need to be logged out on an version upgrade!?

What can you do? For your current upgrade you must log out all users. But you can prepare for next upgrade:

You need to write your own serialization for the session object. Here is one project where they added there own session serialization user Jackson with and some redis library. This code will work without changes even if you are using mysql for example:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/klboke/apollo/091a757d0a3c2173d6c600cd6a9a1595bb73c10c/apollo-portal/src/main/java/com/ctrip/framework/apollo/portal/component/config/SpringSessionConfig.java

One thing to note. So if you are not in production then you add this configuration and when the security lib get upgraded you are fine, but if you are in production first time you deploy this all users will need to be logged out first as serialization of the session will not fit the previous one!

Comment: You don't necessarily have to log users out after the first deploy. You could handle the deserialization exception and use the default conversion logic for older sessions once they expire.

Answer (score -1):

Converters or session repositories does not cover every session failure.
Therefore I have made a hack, that on a specific path we kill the session on the browser side (since the server side jdbc/redis session load cannot recover). On my project the FE logout screen is available if there is an unrecoverable error.

```
@Slf4j
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class RecoverSessionFilter implements Filter {
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        try {
            chain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (((HttpServletRequest) servletRequest).getServletPath().endsWith("/logout")) {
                Cookie cookie = new Cookie("SESSION", null);
                cookie.setPath("/");
                cookie.setHttpOnly(true);
                cookie.setMaxAge(0);
                ((HttpServletResponse) servletResponse).addCookie(cookie);
            }
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```